# [ios8 (Swift)]I add 2 collectionview to my viewcontroller but i cant seperate them in the delegate and Datasource..How?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, collectionview

I have created 2 collectionView in my viewController

> > ```
> >     SchoolActivitycollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
> >    PrivateActivityCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
> >     PrivateActivityCollectionView.delegate = self
> >     PrivateActivityCollectionView.dataSource = self
> >     SchoolActivitycollectionView.delegate = self
> >     SchoolActivitycollectionView.dataSource = self
> > ```

but the problem is in the datasource

> >
>   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    if collectionView == SchoolActivitycollectionView { ..
```

> >

i tried to seperate this 2 collection view i cant. I print out the (`collectionView == SchoolActivitycollectionView`) it shows false .

i have tried `isEaqual()` too .

I just cant seperate them ...so i cant set this 2 collectionview independently...
How can i give set these 2 collectionview up??

Comment: I think my project's structure is a mess..so I m gonna create 2 file and put those 2 collectionview in 2 new viewcontroller.Maybe that will work

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the collection view a tag

```
SchoolActivitycollectionView.tag = 1
PrivateActivityCollectionView.tag = 2
```

Then compare it

```
if collectionView.tag == 1 {
    // SchoolActivity
} else if collectionView.tag == 2 {
    // PrivateActivity
}
```

Comment: the collectionView.tag always return 0...I know how to do now I can create 2 class for those 2 collectionView and make 2 instance here.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
if collectionView == SchoolActivitycollectionView
```

is wrong.

You should use `===` instead to compare two references.

Comment: Currently, I have no time to build an environment to simulate your situation. But theoretically, '===' should work. Maybe you should try imac145's solution. If that fails, there should be some errors in your collection view generation code. One step further, it will be better that you dispatch two collection views' data sources and delegates logic into separate object.